# How to manipulate Json.Encode.Value in Elm?

Tags: json, elm

I'm writing some code to auto-gen JSON codecs for Elm data-structures. There is a point my code, where a "sub-structure/sub-type", has already been encoded to a `Json.Encode.Value`, and I need to add another key-value pair to it. Is there any way to "destructure" a `Json.Encode.Value` in Elm? Or combine two values of type `Json.Encode.Value`?

Here's some sample code:

```
type alias Entity record =
   { entityKey: (Key record)
   , entityVal: record
   }

jsonEncEntity : (record -> Value) -> Entity record -> Value
jsonEncEntity localEncoder_record val =
  let 
      encodedRecord = localEncoder_record val.entityVal
  in
      -- NOTE: the following line won't compile, but this is essentially
      -- what I'm looking for
      Json.combine encodedRecord (Json.Encode.object [ ( "id", jsonEncKey val.entityKey ) ] )
```

Comment: You'd be much better off delaying the encoding such that the sub-structure/sub-type doesn't get encoded until the very last moment; The moment after which you no longer need the original structure. `Json.Encode.Value` is an opaque/black-box (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) data type. Hence, it's not meant to be de-structured. You can save yourself the trouble by re-architecting your application to avoid the need.

Answer (score 3):

You can decode the value into a list of key value pairs using `D.keyValuePairs D.value` and then append the new field. Here's how you'd do that:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Json.Decode as D
import Json.Encode as E exposing (Value)


addKeyValue : String -> Value -> Value -> Value
addKeyValue key value input =
    case D.decodeValue (D.keyValuePairs D.value) input of
        Ok ok ->
            E.object <| ( key, value ) :: ok

        Err _ ->
            input
```

```
> import Main
> import Json.Encode as E
> value = E.object [("a", E.int 1)]
{ a = 1 } : Json.Encode.Value
> value2 = Main.addKeyValue "b" E.null value
{ b = null, a = 1 } : Json.Encode.Value
```

If the input is not an object, this will return the input unchanged:

```
> Main.addKeyValue "b" E.null (E.int 1)
1 : Json.Encode.Value
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using the `decode*` family of methods. It seems very counter-intuitive to first encode something, immediately decode it, then encode it again. Would you know how efficient this decoding is? I tried looking at `Native.Json` module, but wasn't able to understand what's going on there.

Comment: Decoding into key value pairs does 1 iteration of the keys of the JS object and creates a linked list of 2-tuples containing the key and value. Encoding would be the opposite -- take a list of tuples and create object. The values will not be touched if you chain encode/decodes. This should be fairly fast. At least a lot faster than someone would expect if this were similar to JSON.stringify/JSON.parse.

Comment: You may want to confirm what I said above with some benchmarks. This is what I understood from the current master branch of https://github.com/elm/json.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you need to use a decoder to unwrap the values by one level into a `Dict String Value`, then combine the dictionaries, and finally re-encode as a JSON value. You can unwrap like so:

```
unwrapObject : Value -> Result String (Dict String Value)
unwrapObject value =
    Json.Decode.decodeValue (Json.Decode.dict Json.Decode.value) value
```

Notice that you have to work with `Result`s from this point on because there's the possibility, as far as Elm is concerned, that your JSON value wasn't really an object (maybe it was a number or a string instead, for instance) and you have to handle that case. For that reason, it's not really best practice to do too much with JSON `Value`s directly; if you can, keep things as `Dict`s or some other more informative type until the end of processing and then convert the whole result into a `Value` as the last step.